# How to Embed Subtitle to MP4 Without Re-Encoding or ( Is it possible to show Softcoded Subtitle in Web Flash Player )

Tags: video, encoding, video-conversion, subtitles

I have mp4 videos. I need mp4 videos for my website so i dont want to re-encode my mp4 videos to mp4 to add subtitle. I can add subtitle to my videos with MP4Box (with CMD) but it is softcoded. Although i can see subtitle in my MPC(media player classic). I cant see in mywebsite. Is it possible to embed subtitle to mp4 videos without re-encoding or is there anyway to show softcoded subtitle in web ? Or is it possible to quickly encode mp4 to mp4 with subtitle(last option).

Comment: What player are you using on your website?

Comment: NuevoPlayer. it supports flash and html5

Comment: any idea about my problem ?

Comment: look at the free captions plugin available for nuevo player: http://www.nuevolab.com/plugins/captions

Comment: Thanks but I'm already using captions plugin.I dont want to use it because player cant size subtitle in full screen and normal screen. I want to use embeded text track. Nuevo says "the Captions plugin can display Text Tracks embedded into MP4 files." but i cant.

Comment: You can embed the subtitles with ffmpeg, and use `-c copy` to copy the audio and video withour re-encoding. http://ffmpeg.org

Comment: Thank you, i dont know how to use ffmpeg, in website documentation is so long, Where should i look for my problem , -c copy ? I'm using windows.

Comment: I read documentation and did with ffmpeg, there are two ways , burn subtitle (slow proccess) in to mp4, in other word this is hardcoded i could do this before. And the other way ; "embed subtitle" (i could do this too) it is useless for webplayer. I'm looking for forced subtitle, not softcoded and hardcoded. I dont want to re-encode.

Answer (score -1):

There are multiple options to store subtitles in MP4 files. MP4Box can generate all of them:

- 3GPP Timed Text/QuickTime Text Tracks: they can be played with some players, typically Apple products (not sure about Safari)
- WebVTT: currently only mp4box.js can be used (Safari, Chrome) as in this [demo](http://download.tsi.telecom-paristech.fr/gpac/mp4box.js/), look at the "Multiplexed Audio/Video/Subtitle" example
- TTML: the [DASH.js](http://dashif.org/reference/players/javascript/v1.5.0/samples/dash-if-reference-player/index.html) player can play them